# high water pressure in bathtub but not from the shower head!

Tags: water-pressure

why do I have high water pressure in the bathtub but not from the shower head? already changed plumbing and changed the shower head

Comment: What type of difference in pressure are you seeing? Is the pressure from the shower arm increased when the shower head is removed? Is the piping and main valve 3/4" while the shower is only 1/2" pipe? There are several things that can cause this.

Comment: Does "changed the plumbing" mean the shower diverter valve and is in the wall, not a tub spigot pull up.  Some have screens and rubber that can get partly blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a gallon bucket and measure how long it takes to fill the bucket from the tub faucet, the shower head, and the shower pipe without the head on it.  If the time to fill is relatively close between filling with the tub faucet and the headless shower, then it is probably the shower head.  The shower head you buy must not allow more than 2.5 gallons per minute in the US, many are below 2.0 GPM.  There are ways around it, such as modifying your shower head or putting in more than one shower head.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find almost all shower heads have flow restrictiors in them to save water. In the past I have removed these or modified them to provide the flow I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

My three faucet diverter valve had an old dome style washer jammed into the shower pipe in the  valve seat. It took me a while to figure out what was going on. I used an ice pick and piece of wire to remove it. Now pressure is better than before.